# How to fix sorting issue date in datatables column?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have datatables that contain of multiple column of dates. But all the column's date is not work perfectly when sorting asc and desc. Just to inform that all my date is in dd-mm-yyyy format. I am using a function to make it as dd-mm-yyyy.

[image]

I have trying to apply [this](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/41076/how-to-sort-table-by-dd-mm-yyyy) reference but not help. I didn't know whether I am apply in the right way or not, please correct me.

**HTML**

```
<table id="projectListTable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Project Name</th>
            <th>Plan Start</th>
            <th>Plan Finish</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

**JS**

```
jQuery.extend(jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort, {
    "extract-date-pre": function(data) {
        if (data == null){
            return data;
        }
        else {
            new_data = data.split("T");
            new_data[0] = displayDate(new_data[0]);
            return new_data[0];
        }
    },
    "extract-date-asc": function(a, b) {
        return ((a < b) ? -1 : ((a > b) ? 1 : 0));
    },
    "extract-date-desc": function(a, b) {
        return ((a < b) ? 1 : ((a > b) ? -1 : 0));
    }
});    

$('#projectListTable').DataTable({
    columns: [           
        { data : "project_name" },
        { data : "project_planned_start",        
            render: function(data){
                if (data == null){
                    return data;
                }
                else {
                    new_data = data.split("T");
                    new_data[0] = displayDate(new_data[0]);
                    return new_data[0];
                }
            }
        },
        { data : "project_planned_end",
            render: function(data){
                if (data == null){
                    return data;
                }
                else {
                    new_data = data.split("T");
                    new_data[0] = displayDate(new_data[0]);
                    return new_data[0];
                }
            }
        }     
    ],
    columnDefs: [
        {
            type: 'extract-date',
            targets: [1]
        },
        {
            type: 'extract-date',
            targets: [2]
        }
    ]
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your actual date data is in ISO 8601 format.

Example: `2019-03-12T04:08:08.069Z`

You may use in `render` function of each column.

```
{
    data: "project_planned_start",
    render: function(data, type) {
        if (type === 'sort') { // ADD this for sorting
            return data;
        }
        if (data == null) {
            return data;
        } else {
            new_data = data.split("T");
            new_data[0] = displayDate(new_data[0]);
            return new_data[0];
        }
    }
},
```

Comment: this `jQuery.extend...` is still require or not?

Comment: `columnDefs` still require or not?

Comment: If your data is on ISO 8601 format then they are not required. Also for column defs. You can specify both like this `{
            type: 'extract-date',
            targets: [1,2]
        },`

Comment: yes I am using ISO 8601 format. and your answer is working for me. thanks. will accept your answer.

Comment: just to know what is the different between `==` and `===`?

Comment: you can also create a common/helper function for `render`

So you will just re - use them for all columns with date. :D

Comment: Ex: for `==` "1" == 1 -> true, String and Number.  `===` is strict.